# Can't show a MapContainer

Tags: codenameone

I resurrected a CN1 project (already published) and tried to make it run in the simulator under Netbeans 11 (running on OpenJdK 11). However the project kept crashing.

I updated the CN1 Google Maps extension, refreshed the libs, but the problem remained.

So I created a new CN1 project (bare bones with Java 8 project UNticked since it is a Java 11 project) to see if it crashed or not. Actually it showed the "Hi" Form. But then I added a MapContainer like I used to :

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){

        current.show();
        return;
    }

    MapContainer map = new MapContainer("myJAvascriptKey");


    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,map);
    hi.show();
}
```

And the simulator keeps crashing :

`Retina Scale: 1.0
   Rendering frame took too long 163 milliseconds
   [JS Console] Here I am !!!
   Rendering frame took too long 207 milliseconds
   #
   # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
   #
   #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f66f5c69762, pid=13967, tid=14053
   #
   # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.4+11) (build 11.0.4+11-post-Debian-1bpo91)
   # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.4+11-post-Debian-1bpo91, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
   # Problematic frame:
   # V  [libjvm.so+0x89a762]`

The Google Map extension version is 42. What should I do to make everything work as before ?

Any help appreciated,

Comment: FYI Java 8 unticked means using Java 5 not using Java 11. That UI should be removed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the JDK on your project to JDK8.  There is a bug in JavaFX right now that is causing crashes with the web view when run on JDK 11.

Comment: That did the job, thanks Steve! Fortunately I kept JDK8 along side with JDK11!

Comment: I don't know what specific bug in JavaFX you are talking about. At least I don't have any problem running the WebView with the current version of Java/JavaFX (which is 13 and not 11). Why do people always stick to outdated versions and then complain that something isn't working.

Comment: https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/316 They have disregarded it as a configuration issue, and thus closed the issue, but it is indeed an issue.  And the issue occurs with 13 as well as 11.  This is on my list of things to deal with, but it is down there.  Likely we'll end up migrating away from JavaFX